# The startup menu has vanished from my Ubuntu desktop. Now I can't restore factory settings

Tags: menu, settings, restore

[Startup menu does not show - cannot restore factory settings or shut down without pressing the shut down button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaGD8.jpg)

Amongst other problems that have recently popped up out of nowhere, the menu in the right-hand corner of the Ubuntu desktop does not open. This isn't too much of a problem, except that I'd like to restore factory settings and that isn't an available option now. The battery indicator has also vanished and I can't access any battery information. More crucially, my laptop won't recognise drives (but will access an external mouse).

I tried restoring factory settings through the terminal but that didn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

My laptop is a Dell XPS13 developer edition with Ubuntu preinstalled on there.

Comment: If you're willing to do a factory reset, you might want to just reinstall Ubuntu, formatting the partition beforehand.